# Xslt recursion with dynamic xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a problem where i need to generate html from xml and i can have multiple  tags nested in each other. How can i pass them all with recursion?

Here is a sample from the xml:

```
<rows>
   <row>
       <cell>1</cell>
       <cell>2</cell>
       <cell>1</cell>
       <cell>2</cell>
       <row>
         <cell>3</cell>
         <cell>4</cell>
            <row>
              <cell>5</cell>
              <cell>6</cell>
              <cell>6</cell>
           </row>
       </row>
   </row>
 </rows>
```

My xslt is:

```
    <table>
      <th>1</th><th>2</th>3<th>4</th><th>5</th>
      <xsl:for-each select="rows/row">
        <tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="cell">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
         </tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="row">
           <tr>
             <xsl:for-each select="cell">
               <td>
                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </td>
             </xsl:for-each>
           </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>    
       </xsl:for-each>   
     </table>
```

So my question now is how can i show all the atributes in each row?

Edit:Generated html from the xslt

```
<html><body>
<table>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>5</th>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Second edit:

xslt:

```
    <xsl:template match="cell">


     <td style="overflow:hidden;border:1px solid black;">
         <div style="width:100px;height:20px;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 10px;">

           <xsl:variable name="id1" select="row/@id"/>

           <xsl:if test="starts-with(id1, 'Dir')">
               <xsl:value-of select="cell/@image"/>
             </xsl:if>

            <xsl:value-of select="."/>


         </div>
      </td>

   </xsl:template>
```

xml:

```
<row id="Dir_44630">
  <cell>Text</cell>
  <cell>1</cell>
  <cell>1.00</cell>
  <cell>3</cell>
  <cell 4</cell>
  <cell>5</cell>
  <cell>6</cell>
  <cell>7</cell>
</row>
```

Comment: Don't use `for-each`, it will drive you mad. XSLT is a declarative language. It's much easier to base your stylesheet on templates instead of loops. Also, what attributes do you mean? You have none in your example input... or output for that matter.

Comment: By attributes i meant getting the cell values : 1,2,3,4,5 and 6.

Comment: Can you show the desired output for this document? I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Aleks, Please, edit the question and provide the exact *wanted* result from the transformation and also explains the rules for the transformation (what goes where).

Comment: I need to create a tree grid like layout with the given example of xml.I read here on another question i can use templates, but don't know if i can make this layout with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your case, you would start off by having a template to match your root **rows** element

```
<xsl:template match="/rows">
```

In this, you would have to code to build your table header, and then start looking for the child **row** elements

```
<xsl:template match="/rows">
   <table>
      <!-- Header -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
   </table>
</xsl:template>
```

You would then have a template to match **row** elements, so you could output the **tr** elements, and then look for the individual cells

```
<xsl:template match="row">
   <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="cell"/>
   </tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Notice the recursive call to continue to look for **row** elements which are nested in the current **row** element.

Similarly, you would have a template to match the **cell** elements, which would just output a **td** element, and the cell value.

The only thing I am not sure about is your rules about exactly what rows should be output. It looks like you don't want to output **row** elements which are nested two or more levels deep. In this case, you could add a template to ignore rows which have at least two or more rows are ancestors

```
<xsl:template match="row[ancestor::row[2]]"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/rows">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
         </tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row">
      <tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="cell"/>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row[ancestor::row[2]]"/>

   <xsl:template match="cell">
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: If you want to access attributes on the **row** element from within the template that matches the **cell** element, you need to specify that it is the parent element, like so

```
<xsl:variable name="id1" select="../@id"/>
```

Doing `select="row/@id"` will actually look for a row that is a child of the current cell element.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but now i have a problem with displaying an image when the row has id that starts with Dir and when that happens i need to print an image next to the first cell data.Sorry about asking this much but i am new in xslt and it is kind of difficult to understand how it works.I've put my sample in the second edit.

Comment: There is no problem asking questions, but you should really ask a whole new question. It gets confusing if you edit your question with new requirements after it has been answered. It is perfectly fine to start off a new question though.

Comment: The xml and the full solution is displayed here, so i thought that it would be easier for everybody to solve the second problem, i know the question has gotten kind of big so this will be my last edit i promise :).

Comment: I've added a small edit to my answer to show you the way to go in this case.

Comment: Wow that was easy, but who would of known.Thanks again you saved my life today :)